# Getting path under variant_dir when using a hash mark

Tags: scons

### Problem

I have two directories, `a` and `b`, and one's output should be used in the other as input. To achieve this, I use the hash mark syntax (e.g. `b/SConscript` refers to `#a/a2.txt`).
I use `variant_dir` to build into the `build` directory (so `a2.txt` is created in `/home/build/a/a2.txt`).
This combination doesn't work - `#a/a2.txt` is resolved as `/home/a/a2.txt`, but I need `/home/build/a/a2.txt`.

I can add `build` manually (`#/build/a/a2.txt`) but don't like it. First, it may change under some circumstances. Second, SCons always adds the variant_dir itself, so I prefer not to add it manually in some places.

### Example

I build into `build`, and have two directories. `a` copies `a.txt` to the build directory as `a2.txt`. `b` tries to copy it to `b.txt`. Obviously, the copying is just for the example - in reality I do some real processing.
I want to build `b.txt` based on `a2.txt`, which only exists in the build directory. But It tries to use it from the source instead, and fails.

```
% cat SConstruct
SConscript("SConscript", variant_dir="build", duplicate=0)

% cat SConscript
SConscript("a/SConscript")
SConscript("b/SConscript")

% cat a/SConscript
Command("a2.txt", File("a.txt").srcnode(), Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE"))

% cat b/SConscript
Command("b.txt", "#a/a2.txt", Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE"))
```

Output:

```
%  scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: building associated VariantDir targets: build
scons: *** [build/b/b.txt] Source `a/a2.txt' not found, needed by target `build/b/b.txt'.
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

P.S. SCons 2.3.4

Comment: The `#` sign is always resolved such that it refers to the top-level folder of your current build, so the behaviour you see is expected. With this as background, please clarify your question. So far I can only see a few statements that you made, and I'm unsure how exactly I'd be able to help you out.

Comment: @dirkbaechle, I hope I clarified.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a relative path as follows:

```
% cat b/SConscript
Command("b.txt", "../a/a2.txt", Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE"))
```

, instead of the absolute specification with the `#`.

Comment: Works, references with `..` are problematic. what if it's duplicated in multiple directories at different depths?

Answer (score 1):

Even though @dirkbaechle's answer is correct, it has one big limitation - it means that `b` has an implied dependency on the path of `a`. This means you cannot move `a` or `b` without breaking the build, which for larger project isn't really that much more helpful than what you had in your original question.

An alternative way to think about variant directories is simply as a staging area that's used prior to deployment / installation. After you've built your end products, you then want to do something with them (install headers / libraries / binaries). You can see this pattern when you run autotools configure scripts - you have the option to specify a prefix - a location where the final build artefacts would live.

You can mimic this in SCons by adding a (possibly configurable) $PREFIX variable to you Environment. When you need things from your dependencies, you look in a directory below the prefix, rather than traversing up the directory tree.

SConstruct

```
env = Environment()
# project local PREFIX, but could have equally 
# been /usr/local/, /home or some other path
env['PREFIX'] = '#/prefix' 
env.SConscript("SConscript",
                variant_dir="build",
                exports=['env'],
                duplicate=0)
```

SConscript

```
Import('env')
SConscript("a/SConscript", exports=['env'])
SConscript("b/SConscript", exports=['env'])
```

a/SConscript

```
Import('env')

cmd = env.Command('a2.txt', 'a.txt', Copy('$TARGET', '$SOURCE'))
env.Install('$PREFIX', 'a2.txt')
```

b/SConscript

```
Import('env')

env.Command('b.txt', '$PREFIX/a2.txt', Copy('$TARGET', '$SOURCE'))
env.Install('$PREFIX', 'b.txt')
```

Running SCons then gives:

```
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: building associated VariantDir targets: build
Copy("build/a/a2.txt", "a/a.txt")
Install file: "build/a/a2.txt" as "prefix/a2.txt"
Copy("build/b/b.txt", "prefix/a2.txt")
Install file: "build/b/b.txt" as "prefix/b.txt"
scons: done building targets.
```

Comment: 1.) Using relative paths *is* more helpful anyway in large projects, where the tree is large and the full path to the subproject may get veerry long otherwise. 2.) Your usage of the "`variant_dir`" isn't exactly what it's designed for and why it's there. It has more resemblance to VPATH, from my point of view...allowing you to build different variants of your build, in parallel if required.

Comment: @dirkbaechle - agree that this is an abuse of variant_build. But I'm curious, in the case where one library depends on many others, do you just add `../lib[n]/include` to CPPPATH and `#/variant/lib[n]` to LIBPATH for all your dependent libraries SConscripts or do you use helpers of some sort?

Comment: I don't have libaries depending on other libraries (another abuse in my opinion ;) ). In the case where a program requires other libs/headers, yes I include all of them via CPPPATH and LIBPATH. Finally, if the relative location of your project's subfolders (=modules) or their names change, respectively, I fail to see how a build system would know about it...without the user intervening and amending the build description, at least in a few spots.